# Azure cli repository import fails with Operation returned a 400 status code

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, azure-cli

> **What specific syntax and/or configuration needs to be changed below in order for an Azure CLI command to successfully import a private source repo from GitHub into a private destination repo in Azure Repos?**

**CURRENT COMMAND AND ERROR RESPONSE:**

```
C:\path\to\working\directory>az repos import create --git-source-url https://github.com/ValidGitHubOrgName/valid-gh-repo-name --repository ValidAzureReposDestinationRepoName --organization https://dev.azure.com/ValidOrgName --project ValidProjectName --requires-authorization  
Git Password / PAT:  
Confirm Git Password / PAT:  
ClientRequestError: Operation returned a 400 status code.
```

**WHAT WORKS:**

When we use the above to import a **public** repository from GitHub into a private Azure Repos repo, the above completes without error as along as we of course remove the `--requires-authorization` flag.

**WHAT FAILS:**

However the above fails when we try to import a **private** GitHub repository with the full syntax shown above.

We have tried this not only with a valid GitHub password but also with a valid Azure DevOps Personal Access token that we give when prompted as shown above.

> **Do we need to add configuration in order for the import to work without error?**
> **And also, how can we make sure the import command executes without an interactive request of credentials?**

This needs to run in automation without an interactive human user.

The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/import?view=azure-cli-latest) does not seem to include the instructions we require.

Comment: your GitHub is public or private ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue on my side, to use Azure CLI import a private GitHub repo to DevOps via a non-interactive way, please follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the `Project Settings` in the devops portal -> `Service connections` ->  `New service connection` -> `Other Git`(Not `GitHub`) -> create the connection with your github username and password.

[image]

2.Use REST API - [`Endpoints - Get Service Endpoints By Names`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get%20service%20endpoints%20by%20names?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) or CLI [`az devops service-endpoint list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/service-endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest#az_devops_service_endpoint_list) to get the service connection, then note down the `id`(there are not only one `id`, use the correct one as below).

[image]

[image]

3.Then run the command as below, pass `id` in step 2 to `--git-service-endpoint-id`, also make sure you have created the devops repo and it is empty.

```
az repos import create --git-source-url https://github.com/Joyw1/privaterepo.git --repository testrep6 --git-service-endpoint-id 3c04f8a9-43c8-40cb-baf5-90faf292b9ab --organization https://dev.azure.com/xxxx --project testpro1 --requires-authorization
```

[image]

Check the result:

[image]

**Update:**

To create the `Other Git` service connection in an automatic way, you could powershell to call the [REST API - Endpoints - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#create-service-endpoint) directly.

Sample:

```
$MyPat = '<your devops PAT>'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))

$header = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + $B64Pat
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

$body = '{
  "data": {},
  "name": "MyNewServiceEndpoint",
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/Joyw1/privaterepo.git",
  "authorization": {
    "parameters": {
      "username": "joyw1",
      "password": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "scheme": "UsernamePassword"
  },
  "isShared": false,
  "isReady": true,
  "serviceEndpointProjectReferences": [
    {
      "projectReference": {
        "id": "53f719f7-2968-4035-8e56-163f239b4161",
        "name": "testpro1"
      },
      "name": "MyNewServiceEndpoint"
    }
  ]
}'

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://dev.azure.com/v-joyw/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=6.0-preview.4 -Headers $header -Body $body
```

[image]

Comment: @CodeMed Try the password insteaf of PAT of github, PAT seems not work on my side.

Comment: @CodeMed I never used the `AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_GIT_SOURCE_PASSWORD_OR_PAT` env var, did you use the service connection as I mentioned above? Please follow my answer completely, don't add additional things.

Comment: @CodeMed Could you make sure the type of the service connection is `Other Git` and pass the correct username and password(not PAT)?

Comment: @CodeMed Per my test, the `GitHub` service connection will not work, you need to use `Other Git`, I have mentioned it in my reply, could you please try it manually?

Comment: @CodeMed You could use CLI [`az devops service-endpoint create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/service-endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest#az_devops_service_endpoint_create) or REST API [`Endpoints - Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), to test it manually first, I just want to confirm `Other git` works for you, if so, you just need to look into the configuration/body of the CLI/REST API, if not, all is meaningless, right?

Comment: @CodeMed For an automatic way, just use powershell to call the REST API, see my update.

Comment: Thank you for the time and energy that you devoted to our question.

Answer (score 2):

for Integration with GitHub (Private) the current az cli have no option to take password therefore showing you interactive credential input, therefore the suggestion is to set environment variable **AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_GIT_SOURCE_PASSWORD_OR_PAT** as part your batch/shell script
and it will work , the suggest issue is open and work upon according to https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/1050

Comment: We added a description of the steps we took to follow your instructions to the end of our OP.  What else can we try?